# Modify UITableViewController data from child Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have two controllers. On cell click my UITableViewController(**A**) navigates to child UIViewController(**B**) through

```swift
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

In the **B** I edit cell's specific data and return back to the tableViewController
To execute **A** data update I use delegation. So **B** executes **A** "edit" function to update the row with **A**'s method:

```swift
rows.insert(row, at: 0)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

But when I try to do it, I receive an Xcode warning:

> UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy...

As I understand, to update the **A** it needs to be visible. Table updates but I do something wrong for sure.

Is there a way to avoid this warning using delegation pattern or I should consider another method?

Comment: Don't call `tableView.beginUpdates()` etc, only modify the model (which I guess is `rows`) in that delegate method, since the TableView isn't visible.

Comment: @Larme, tried this. Same thing. If to follow instructions from console and add a symbolic breakpoint "UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy", then I can see it initiated from .insertRows

Comment: @iwazovsky - first, don't call it a "Child" controller... that's a different thing. You can use the protocol/delegate pattern or a closure (closures are considered more "Swifty"). Assuming you have something like a "Save" button in **B**, you would either call a delegate func or the closure and `pop` the controller. In **A**, the func would update your data source and then reload the selected cell.